# insert from java servlet to mysql, insert statement not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql, servlets

I have been going at this for several hours now, and have been googling around and I cant seem to resolve it.

When I run the code, I get an exception and the top of the stacktrace tells me I have an sql syntax error, but I can't spot it.

I have tried several solutions but I am still drawing blanks, any help is appreciated

Thanks
Peter

```
private String insertBookingKnownUser(Connection connection,
     HttpServletRequest request) throws SQLException
     {


  try
  {
     String queryString = "INSERT INTO booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
     statement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
     int hotelNumber = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("hotelNumber"));
     //REMEMBER TO CHANGE GUESTNUMBER
     int guestNumber = 1;
     DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
     Date dateFrom;
     dateFrom = (Date)formatter.parse(request.getParameter("dateFrom"));
     java.sql.Date sqlDateFrom = new java.sql.Date(dateFrom.getTime()); 
     Date dateTo = (Date)formatter.parse(request.getParameter("dateTo"));
     java.sql.Date sqlDateTo = new java.sql.Date(dateTo.getTime()); 
     int roomNumber= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("roomNumber"));

     statement.setInt(1, hotelNumber);
     statement.setInt(2, guestNumber);
     statement.setDate(3, sqlDateFrom);
     statement.setDate(4, sqlDateTo);
     statement.setInt(5, roomNumber);
     statement.executeUpdate(queryString);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return "";
     }
```

edit: removed a semicolon, still get the same error

Stacktrace:

```
statementcom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1402)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1317)
 at SimpleServlet.insertBookingKnownUser(SimpleServlet.java:227)
 at SimpleServlet.doGet(SimpleServlet.java:81)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: remove the `;` from the end of the statement

Comment: Removed it, but still getting the same exception

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Maybe one of your column name isn't right. We'd need the stacktrace to check that

Comment: Posted it now, thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `statement.executeUpdate()` instead of `statement.executeUpdate(queryString)`.

When you call `executeUpdate()` it takes into account the arguments you set on the statement before but when you call `executeUpdate(String s)` it just executes the given query without the set parameters.

Comment: That worked!
Thanks a lot, had tried it earlier without, not sure what changed since, but thanks for taking the time!